# Is it correct/possible to get data from TABLE inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. I want to get data from table and use it as Array:

```
$InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` = '.$value['id_seller']);
```

However the result of "**$value['id_seller']**" is coming from this:

```
foreach ($SellerIn as $key => $value) {
  $value['id_seller']    
}
```

**$SellerIn** - is a DB query to a different table

So is it correct to do it like this:

```
foreach ($SellerIn as $key => $value) {
   $value['id_seller']
   $InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` = '.$value['id_seller']);    
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `where id_seller IN $sellerin` and then loop through the results, rather than loop through the ids and query every time

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible but it's really bad for the performance. 
If you have heavy traffic on your website you would want to hit the DB as little as possible.

So in order to optimise a situation like that you can use WHERE IN.

Something like this:

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($SellerIn as $key => $value) {
    $ids[] = $value['id_seller'];
}
$InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` IN ('.implode(",",$ids).')');
```

**EDIT**:
You said that

> $SellerIn - is a DB query to a different table

So you can just mix the 2 queries into one

```
$InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` IN ( SELECT id FROM different_table WHERE condition )');
```

Answer (score 1):

This does sound correct, but it will make SQL query for each element in `$SellerIn` - which can be very slow:

```
foreach ($SellerIn as $key => $value) {
   $InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` = '.$value['id_seller']);    
}
```

Better solution would be to make 1 query and check `id_seller` with `IN`:

```
$all_ids = implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['id_seller'];
}, $SellerIn));

$InRating = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'seller_review`  WHERE `id_seller` IN ('.$all_ids.')');
```